# iterating dicts out of a dict of matched-length lists

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

I have this structure:

```
d = {
    "a": [1, 2, 3],
    "b": [4, 5, 6],
    "c": [7, 8, 9],
}
```

The lengths of the lists are guaranteed to match. I want an iterator I can for-loop over that will serve up a dict for each column in the lists, sort of like a zip turned back into a dict with the original key names each time, like this:

```
>>> for i in iDictOfListsToDicts(d):
...     print  i
{"a": 1, "b": 4, "c": 7}
{"a": 2, "b": 5, "c": 8}
{"a": 3, "b": 6, "c": 9}
```

I'm sure I could hack something in a generator function, but I feel like I'm missing a tight little combo of maybe two things, perhaps from collections and/or itertools. I'd like decent efficiency and readability if possible.

I've been toying with things that begin like this:

```
map(iter, d.values())
```

Obviously that just gives me a list of iterators of values with no related keys, though, and I still can't for-loop over that list and get what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) or use [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) with `None`:

```
>>> zip([1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9])
[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
>>> map(None, [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9])
[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

Try following:

```
def iDictOfListsToDicts(d):
    keys = list(d)
    for vs in zip(*d.values()):
        yield dict(zip(keys, vs))
```

example:

```
>>> d = {
...     "a": [1, 2, 3],
...     "b": [4, 5, 6],
...     "c": [7, 8, 9],
... }
>>> for i in iDictOfListsToDicts(d):
...     print i
... 
{'a': 1, 'c': 7, 'b': 4}
{'a': 2, 'c': 8, 'b': 5}
{'a': 3, 'c': 9, 'b': 6}
```

Comment: I was using zip, but fumbling with the parts around it :) Anyway, that's it. I knew there was a simple, small answer. Thanks.